# How to start a specific song in spotify/iTunes

Tags: macos, swift, itunes, spotify

If I have access to information like : song name, artist, album, would it be possible to perform a search on spotify/iTunes (or even Apple Music) and start the song (if the search is successful) within the desktop client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spotify**

Spotify has now a SDK for iOS but it will only works on iOS and NOT on OS X.
[Source - Frequently Asked Questions about the iOS SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/)

**iTunes**

iTunes has some unofficial frameworks that may help you. I found this one named "[EyeTunes](http://www.liquidx.net/eyetunes/)" which can let you do what you want as said in your questions. (perform a search and launch a song).
But, it is **unofficial**.

**Apple Music**

Today, no SDK or API has been announced so for the moment it is not a solution.

Comment: Thanks ! Also, I found this : [Spotify and AppleScript](]https://developer.spotify.com/applescript-api/). If I understand that correctly, I can start a song with AppleScript if I have the spotify id of that track. Maybe I can use spotify web api to find the track id based on the track and album names ?

Comment: Yes, it could be a good idea, I think it could work. And if it answered your question, don't forget to check my answer as the answer to your question :) Thank you